# Remote json parsing in Swift

Tags: json, swift

```
[
  -{ 
      valid:"2",
      invalid: "1",
      pending: "2"
   },
  -{ 
      valid:"0",
      invalid: "1",
      pending: "0"
   },
  -{
      valid:"2",
      invalid: "1",
      pending: "2"
   }
]
```

I am trying to parse this remote json and populate the data into an array.
I am struggling for hours trying to find out why my code isn't working,the array always ends up being empty. can somebody please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

```
  var arrayreports : [Report] = []
    var report  = Report()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let host =  appDelegate.host
    if(Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()){

        let postEndpoint: String = host+"/api/reportbyworkflow/7"

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!

        session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
                realResponse.statusCode == 201 else {


                    print("Bad thing happened")
                    return
            }

            do {


                if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {


                    let jsonDictionary:AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                     let json = jsonDictionary as? Array<AnyObject>


                     for index in 0...json!.count-1 {
                        let contact : AnyObject? = json![index]
                        print(contact)

                        let collection = contact! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    let valid = collection["valid"] as! String
                    let invalid = collection["invalid"] as! String
                    let pending = collection["pending"] as! String

                    report!.valid = Double(Int(valid)!)
                    report!.invalid = Double(Int(invalid)!)
                    report!.pending = Double(Int(pending)!)


                        arrayreports.append(report!)
                    }

                }}


            catch {

                print("bad things happened")


            }



        }).resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your json is really the one you copied here, it is not valid ( check on jsonvalidator.com ).

So it is normal than your serialization returns an empty array